# behaviour or pattern recognition?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, pattern-recognition

I am getting the gps position and time of a voluntary person which moves around. I am acquiring the position every second with Matlab and save it in a matrix.
Now I would like to be able to say if the person is moving normal or not. For example running in circles is not normal for a person who usually only walks around.

I am not looking for a complete solution because I would like to learn through my project and understand every aspect. I would be very grateful if you could show me the right direction. Good literature, tutorials and simple catchwords would also be very helpful for me because at the moment I dont know how to approach my problem.

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards,
Tom

Comment: Unfortunately, this post isn't such a good fit for the StackOverflow format... that said, look into machine learning. It might give some hints of how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is anomaly detection. The primary commercial application of this technology is in fraud detection. As for pointing to resources any books that cover data mining should have a section about anomaly detection.

Something to for warn you about, it sounds from your description that you will be working with time series data which is its own branch of data mining.

Catchwords: Anomaly Detection, and Time Series Data.
Books: ISBN-13 978-0321321367 Introduction to Data Mining (This is a good starting point if you don't have a lot of background in the subject)